# pycharm and pyinstaller confusion

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have been writing `.py` scripts using PyCharm in Windows 10. I want to compile them into standalone `.exe` so I installed pyinstaller. I believe I made a mistake by installing it via the terminal inside PyCharm instead of `cmd`.

Pyinstaller was initially installed in `C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\routine\venv\Scripts`

(`\routine\` is the name of the project where I keep my scripts for tasks I do on a routine basis.)

When I DIR in `\Scripts`, I can see pyinstaller.exe

When I run pyinstaller from `\Scripts`, I get the following error:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\myuser\pycharmprojects\routine tasks\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\routine\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.`

If I try to run pyinstaller from a different directory, I get this message: `"'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."`

If I try to install pyinstaller from anywhere else, I get a bunch of messages saying `"Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages"`

If I uninstall pyinstaller with pip and then reinstall it, I get this message `"WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH."`

If I add the specified directory to PATH I still get the same message.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, or any suggestions as to how to fix this?